# Why do we have to add forward slash in the file directory to differentiate between directory and files?

Tags: java, file, directory, backslash

Inside a `for` loop:

Why do I have to add a forward slash after the directory name?
For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
    File f = new File(dirname + "/" + s[i] ); 
    // Why to add "/" after dirname(i.e directory name)
    if(f.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println(s[i] + " is Directory" );
    }else{
        System.out.println(s[i] + " is File");
    }
}
```

If I remove backslash "/" after `dirname`:

```
File f = new File(dirname + "/" + s[i] );
```

When I remove "/":

```
File f = new File(dirname + s[i] );
```

It won't differentiate between directory and file. All the files inside will be considered to be the file. 
After I add a backslash, it will be okay. And it will differentiate between directory and file. Why is that?
Why do I have to add "/". The program is meant to look inside the file without adding "/".

Comment: We can't say until we know what variables such as `s` and `dirname` are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including and omitting the `/` mean that the file points to a different path. For example, `"foo/bar"` and `"foobar"` are different paths, which would point to different objects in the file system:

```
Parent directory
+-- foobar     "foobar"
+-- foo
    +-- bar    "foo/bar"
```

Not being a directory is not the same thing as being a file. So, most likely (we don't know what's in your file system), it's not a directory because it doesn't exist.

You should check `if (!f.exists())` (or similar) first:

```
if (!f.exists()) System.out.println("Doesn't exist");
else if (f.isDirectory()) ... etc
```

Also, note that you shouldn't add a `/` anyway - use the two-arg constructor:

```
File f = new File(dirname, s[i] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

Slash symbol is a [file separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator). This is used to separate the directories from the files.

If you are to build your string, the file name will be:

```
Pictures/my-dog.png
```

Here, you will see that there is a directory named "Picture" and a filename "my-dog.png".

If you were to remove the slash, it will look like a long filename:

```
Picturesmy-dog.png
```